# Java replacing ampersand in XML file

Tags: java, xml

I am processing a list of URLS containing XML files. My problem is that some of them are not well formed because they contain "&"(ampersand) characters,l so my code cannot parse it correctly.

```
<elementType>CK037 - AT&ZN -SET</elementType>
```

How could I avoid this?? Should I first read the XML as a String and replace the "&" with "amp;" ?? Are there any other more appropiate solutions for my problem??

This is my code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new URL(inputURLString).openStream());
    (...)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing a replace seems fine.

Comment: A replace on a *valid* XML document will of course end up with `&amp;amp;` which you don't want... I would personally work on fixing the original XML if you possibly can - if it's been produced that badly to start with, who knows what other problems it might have. What are these URLs? What kind of documents are they, and do you have any influence on them? If you can get them fixed, it won't just help you, but also anyone else reading them...

Comment: First is to tell the author of the XML it is invalid and the data will be rejected as required by the specifications - only when they say the can't meet specifications then use a replace

Comment: If it starts like this, you'll have a lot of other problems as well, e.g. for the < character. And then you're really in deep trouble.

Comment: I do not own the XML I am accessing. I have already contacted these XML file providers, but it seems fixing them is not in their near-future plans. That is why I was asking. I guess I have no choice but to read the file first as a String, do all replacements needed, and then parse it, right?

Comment: Start by changing your attitude. It's not an XML file, it's a non-XML file. If you want to parse data that isn't governed by any standard, and for which you can't get an off-the-shelf parser, then the first thing you need to do is to write a specification of the data you need to handle: exactly what deviations from XML do you want to tolerate? Better still, get the creator of the file to produce real XML - there are good reasons for standards, you know.